enter a substring and a string and remove substring from string in C
I cannot run this following code since getting segmentation fault. In the main i enter a string and a substring, whereas in the function i catch the substring and remove it from the string using memmove.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeSubstring(char *s, const char *r) {
    int len = strlen(r);
    char *pos;

    while ((pos = strstr(s, r)) != NULL) {
        memmove(pos, pos + len, strlen(pos + len) + 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    char *s;
    const char *r;

    printf("Enter the first string: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &s); 

    printf("Enter the second string: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &r);

    removeSubstring(s, r);

    printf("Modified string: %s\n", s);

    return 0;
}

i receive a segmentation fault

s and r must be defined as true arrays, not just as pointers. And when passing them to scanf, don't take their addresses; they are converted to pointers automatically.

scanf(" %[^\n]s", &r); Doesn't your compiler complain about providing wrong type for argument for %[] format specifier? You must pass a pointer to char but you pass a pointer to pointer to char. Also, [] is not a modifier for %s. Therefore %[^\n]s requires an extra s to be entered.

There's no %[...]s format. The format is just %[...], without the trailing s. And I really recommend you use fgets to read lines, and it's easy to remove the trailing newline. It's also much easier to do input validation and check for errors, something which your code does not do but it should.

Study arrays then pointers then strings in that particular order.

    char *s;
    const char *r;


Those pointers are not initialized and do not reference valid char arrays required by the scanf function. It invoked undefined behaviour.
Also you cant modify the const object.
also scanf(" %[^\n]s", &s); is wrong as you pass pointer to pointer to char.
Change to:
    char s[128];
    char r[128];

    printf("Enter the first string: ");
    scanf(" %127s", s); 

    printf("Enter the second string: ");
    scanf(" %127s", r);
    

(128 is just an example)

I would go so far as to say that fgets() is the better tool for this.
